# System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Paramete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stimulsoft

iam use mvc5.2 and stimulsoft 2014.3 when run this see error:
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key

> Source Error:
>
> Line 7:    Line 8:
>   @Html.Stimulsoft().RenderMvcViewerScripts() Line 9:
>   @Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer("MyViewr", new StiMvcViewerOptions()
>   Line 10:    { Line 11:        ActionGetReportSnapshot =
>   "FromLoadFileReport",

```
    @Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer("MyViewr", new StiMvcViewerOptions()
  {
      ActionGetReportSnapshot = "FromLoadFileReport",
      ActionViewerEvent = "ViewerEvent",
      Width = Unit.Percentage(100)
      //Theme = StiTheme.Office2007Black,
      //ActionPrintReport = "PrintReport",
      //ActionExportReport = "ExportReport",
      //ToolbarBackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver



  StiReport report = new StiReport();
        string Path = Server.MapPath("~" + ("/Web/Areas/RepUser/HistoryJob.mrt"));
        report.Load(Path);
        report.Compile();

        return StiMvcViewer.GetReportSnapshotResult(HttpContext, report);
```

[image: show this error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add next section in Web.config file:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: I have this code in my config:<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly> but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

stimulsoft 2014 Doesn't Support MVC5.
you should download Stimulsoft 2015.2.

Stimulsoft Reports.Web 2014.1
This version of the product compatible with .NET Framework 2.0 - 3.5

Stimulsoft Reports.Web 2015.2 Official Release
An installation package contains everything to install or uninstall the product and to run the setup user interface. This product compatible with Visual Studio 2010 - 2015 and .NET Framework 4.0 or higher.

https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/downloads/reports-web
https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/changes/reports-web?build=2015.2