# 'System.ArgumentNullException' while using Stimulsoft

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, stimulsoft

I'm trying to use Stimulsoft Reports 2014.3 in my MVC 5.2 app. I get the following exception when I try to use `@Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer`.

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key

I can use `@Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewerFx` just fine. I have tried various changes in web.config to get ride of this exception, but they were all useless. I've also tried Debug -> Exceptions, and checking both boxes for Common Language Runtime Exceptions, but there wasn't any other exception.

Adding `@Html.Stimulsoft().RenderMvcViewerScripts()` wasn't useful neither.

This is the view:

```
@using Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@model Models.GenericReportViewModel

<div>
    @Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer(new StiMvcViewerOptions()
{
    ActionGetReportSnapshot = string.Concat("LoadReport?Id=", Model.ReportName),
    Width = Unit.Point(500),
    Theme = StiTheme.Default,
    ActionExportReport = "ExportReport",
    Height = Unit.Point(400),
    Controller = "Report",
})
</div>
```

This is the web.config:

```
  <system.web>
      <globalization uiCulture="fa-IR" culture="fa-IR"></globalization>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="Stimulsoft.Base, Version=2014.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ebe6666cba19647a" />
        <add assembly="Stimulsoft.Report, Version=2014.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ebe6666cba19647a" />
        <add assembly="Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc, Version=2014.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ebe6666cba19647a" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <!--<add namespace="System.Web.Abstractions" />-->
        <add namespace="Stimulsoft.Base" />
        <add namespace="Stimulsoft.Report" />
        <add namespace="Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
```

I should note that the Flash version works as below and it doesn't have any problem:

```
@using Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@model Models.GenericReportViewModel

<div>
    @Html.Stimulsoft().RenderMvcViewerFxScripts()
    @Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewerFx(new StiMvcViewerFxOptions()
{
    ActionGetReportSnapshot = string.Concat("LoadReport?Id=", Model.ReportName),
    Width = Unit.Point(500),
    Theme = StiMvcViewerFxOptions.Themes.Blue,
    ActionExportReport = "ExportReport",
    BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver,
    ActionGetLocalization = "GetLocal",
    Height = Unit.Point(400),
    Controller = "Report",
})
</div>
```

It's been [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30778740/3967440) to add the following `bindingRedirect` to `web.config`

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Adding this will suppress the exception and prevents the page from rendering, probably because I'm not using MVC 3! But it should have something to do with it.

I also have this redirect as `oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"`, but I'll get the exception with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in appsettings in web.config

```
<add key="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Disabled" />
```

Maybe your report file created with different version of Stimulsoft.